# In Google Sheets remove serie of ngrams from cells containing lists of comma separated ngrams in primary sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, nlp, google-sheets-formula, stop-words

Have been working in Google Sheets on a general table containing approximately a thousand texts. In one column derived form the column containing the texts in their original "written" form, are ngrams (words and the like) extracted from them, and listed in alphabetic order, one list of ngrams corresponding to each text. I’ve been trying without success to derive a second column, from these lists of such ngrams, from which I want to remove instances of certain ngrams of which I have a list (a long list, hundreds of ngrams, and a list to which I could make additions later). In other words, from the text mining vocabulary, I want to remove stop words from lists of tokens.

[image]

I tried with SPLIT and REGEXREPLACE functions, or a combination of both, but with no success.

```
=JOIN(",";SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(AL3;"\bau\b;\baux\b;\bavec\b;\bce\b;\bces\b;\bdans\b;\bde\b;\bdes\b;\bdu\b;\belle\b;\ben\b;\bet\b;\beux\b;\bil\b;\bje\b;\bla\b;\ble\b;\bleur\b;\blui\b;\bma\b;\bmais\b;\bme\b;\bmême\b;\bmes\b;\bmoi\b;\bmon\b;\bne\b;\bnos\b;\bnotre\b;\bnous\b;\bon\b;\bou\b;\bpar\b;\bpas\b;\bpour\b;\bqu\b;\bque\b;\bqui\b;\bsa\b;\bse\b;\bses\b;\bson\b;\bsur\b;\bta\b;\bte\b;\btes\b;\btoi\b;\bton\b;\btu\b;\bun\b;\bune\b;\bvos\b;\bvotre\b;\bvous\b;\bc\b;\bd\b;\bj\b;\bl\b;\bà\b;\bm\b;\bn\b;\bs\b;\bt\b;\by\b;\bété\b;\bétée\b;\bétées\b;\bétés\b;\bétant\b;\bsuis\b;\bes\b;\best\b;\bsommes\b;\bêtes\b;\bsont\b;\bserai\b;\bseras\b;\bsera\b;\bserons\b;\bserez\b;\bseront\b;\bserais\b;\bserait\b;\bserions\b;\bseriez\b;\bseraient\b;\bétais\b;\bétait\b;\bétions\b;\bétiez\b;\bétaient\b;\bfus\b;\bfut\b;\bfûmes\b;\bfûtes\b;\bfurent\b;\bsois\b;\bsoit\b;\bsoyons\b;\bsoyez\b;\bsoient\b;\bfusse\b;\bfusses\b;\bfût\b;\bfussions\b;\bfussiez\b;\bfussent\b;\bayant\b;\beu\b;\beue\b;\beues\b;\beus\b;\bai\b;\bas\b;\bavons\b;\bavez\b;\bont\b;\baurai\b;\bauras\b;\baura\b;\baurons\b;\baurez\b;\bauront\b;\baurais\b;\baurait\b;\baurions\b;\bauriez\b;\bauraient\b;\bavais\b;\bavait\b;\bavions\b;\baviez\b;\bavaient\b;\beut\b;\beûmes\b;\beûtes\b;\beurent\b;\baie\b;\baies\b;\bait\b;\bayons\b;\bayez\b;\baient\b;\beusse\b;\beusses\b;\beût\b;\beussions\b;\beussiez\b;\beussent\b;\bceci\b;\bcela\b;\bcelà\b;\bcet\b;\bcette\b;\bici\b;\bils\b;\bles\b;\bleurs\b;\bquel\b;\bquels\b;\bquelle\b;\bquelles\b;\bsans\b;\bsoi\b";"");" ")));"")
```

Dumky [here](https://www.dumky.net/posts/tf-idf-in-google-sheets-implementing-text-analysis-keyword-counting-tokenisation-and-stemming-in-a-spreadsheet/) has done something neat, writing a script with custom functions that does a couple of things, among them calling a list from a secondary sheet, to clean such lists of ngrams-words-tokens, but what he has done exceed both what I want to do, and what I can do in Google Sheets on my own.

An exemple of a list of stop words (ngrams to remove):
à,ai,aie,aient,aies,ait,as,au,aura,aurai,auraient,aurais,aurait,auras,aurez,auriez,aurions,aurons,auront,aux,avaient,avais,avait,avec,avez,aviez,avions,avons,ayant,ayez,ayons,c,ce,ceci,cela,celà,ces,cet,cette,d,dans,de,des,du,elle,en,es,est,et,étaient,étais,était,étant,été,étée,étées,êtes,étés,étiez,étions,eu,eue,eues,eûmes,eurent,eus,eusse,eussent,eusses,eussiez,eussions,eut,eût,eûtes,eux,fûmes,furent,fus,fusse,fussent,fusses,fussiez,fussions,fut,fût,fûtes,ici,il,ils,j,je,l,la,le,les,leur,leurs,lui,m,ma,mais,me,même,mes,moi,mon,n,ne,nos,notre,nous,on,ont,ou,par,pas,pour,qu,que,quel,quelle,quelles,quels,qui,s,sa,sans,se,sera,serai,seraient,serais,serait,seras,serez,seriez,serions,serons,seront,ses,soi,soient,sois,soit,sommes,son,sont,soyez,soyons,suis,sur,t,ta,te,tes,toi,ton,tu,un,une,vos,votre,vous,y

An exemple of the output I am looking for —

List of ngrams derived from a short text:
10,11,21,à,à,ami,ami,amour,aux,baiser,brusko,brusko,car,ce,comme,comme,compagnon,de,de,déclare,déclare,déteste,électricité,elle,en,est,est,est,et,étudiant,fluide,gare,germes,heures,idéalistes,il,infectueux,je,l,l,la,la,le,lumière,médecine,meilleur,moi,moi,mon,montréal,pée,pensez,poète,que,que,qui,rancune,répondez,sans,science,ses,sic,un,un,vébicule,vôtre,vous

Output:
ami,ami,amour,baiser,brusko,brusko,car,comme,comme,compagnon,déclare,déclare,déteste,électricité,étudiant,fluide,gare,germes,heures,idéalistes,infectueux,lumière,médecine,meilleur,montréal,pée,pensez,poète,rancune,répondez,science,sic,vébicule,vôtre

[image]

Comment: Probably I'm not bright enough. Could you please to make a short sample: cell(s) that you have and cell(s) that you want to have? Don't need to use all the hundreds words and those ngrams. Just a few, 5-10, as example. If it will work with 5 words it will work with 500 or 5000 words about as well.

Comment: Hello @YuriKhristich, and thank you for considering my question. I’ve edit the question to provide an exemple as you request.

Comment: It looks like the code in my answer does the job. The next step is to make it woks with your spreadsheet. Do you have a problem with this? Only possible problem I can think if the texts are really huge the script can excess maximal time to run.

Comment: The list of 'stop words' is the same for all rows?

Comment: The longest list has a little over 6000 ngrams in it. This is about as long as it could get. I don’t expect a problem of that sort. Indeed, the list of stop words is the same for all rows. However, I might have to make multiple additions to it over time. The code snippet you provided does the jobs perfectly it seems!

Comment: @YuriKhristich thank you! It works when I execute the script from the consol. Could I do the same from the sheet, using the function?

Comment: I get an error message when I try: "You do not have permission to call setValues (row 15)." However, I have created custom function only twice, and it might be a basic thing I don’t do right.

Comment: This is not a custom function. This is a script. You need to open Tools > Script Editor. To paste the code inside the editor. And to hit the Run button. But it could work wrong anyway, since I used columns B, C, D in my example. The data in your sheet is placed into another columns. Probably AK, AL, AM, I don't know. You need to refine my sample for your spreadsheet. Or you can share a dummy copy of your real spreadsheet and I can try to refine my script.

Comment: I did't explained me well. Sorry about that. I’ve tried the scripts in the Script Editor (what I called "the console"). What I am trying to do, is to create a function from the script, by replacing the cell references (B2, C2, etc.) with "value 1", "value 2", but this is where I get lost, and I get this message of error, when I try to use the resulting custom function in the sheet.

Comment: I think a custom function is not the best idea for this particular task. Custom functions are good for small fast calculations. I'm afraid it wont work well for thousands rows with hundreds words in a cell to check. A static script is more solid solution. You can add custom menu on your Spreadsheet to run the script. Say, menu 'Check all rows' and meny 'Check current row'. Or 'Check selected rows'

Comment: Nevertheless I've added a sample of custom function in my answer.

Comment: Third one works too, like a charm. You’ve helped me big time here @YuriKhristich! And patient beside that. May I ask you one last thing? Using the custom function NGRAMSFILTER, I can only refer to a single cell (ex. B2). But what if my stop words list is in a column? What should I do to have instead a range of cells for the first value (ex. B2:B)?

Comment: Do you want take the 'stop words' from 'a range' (several cells, like 'B2:B')? I think it can be done. But you need to describe your workflow. Probably the easies way would be to wire this range inside the function. So the function will get only one argument -- 'ngrams'. And 'stop words' it will get always from `'B2:B'+last_row` range. What do you think?

Comment: That is what I would want to do: take the stop words from a range ("B2:B"). They are two or three reasons why that would be optimal. One, they are not one but many list of stop words, by different programmers and linguists, and it is useful to derive more than one filtered ngrams lists in the main table. Two, spreading the stop words in cells through columns makes it easier to consult the lists, spot incongruities, and eventually make changes and add-ons to the default lists. In the same spreadsheet, I have a distinct secondary sheet in which each column is filed with a particular list.

Comment: Ok. I'll try to implement it. But there is a chance that it won't work well for too many rows. A static script is a more robust solution for this case.

Comment: Works great too! Again, you’ve really helped me. I wish we could add multiple arrow ups. It is slower like you said, anyway I’ll keep all the variations in the script editor, and keep in mind the warnings you gave me about potential calculation issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to remove some words from some string then basically it can be done this way:

```js
var txt = "a,b,c,d,aa,bb,cc,dd";

var to_remove = "a,bb,d,dd".split(',');

results = txt.split(',').filter(word => !to_remove.includes(word)).join();

console.log(results); //output: 'b,c,aa,cc'
```

But there are need additional steps to make it works with a spreadsheet data of course.

**Update**

The same code with the test data:

```js
var txt = "10,11,21,à,à,ami,ami,amour,aux,baiser,brusko,brusko,car,ce,comme,comme,compagnon,de,de,déclare,déclare,déteste,électricité,elle,en,est,est,est,et,étudiant,fluide,gare,germes,heures,idéalistes,il,infectueux,je,l,l,la,la,le,lumière,médecine,meilleur,moi,moi,mon,montréal,pée,pensez,poète,que,que,qui,rancune,répondez,sans,science,ses,sic,un,un,vébicule,vôtre,vous";

var to_remove = "à,ai,aie,aient,aies,ait,as,au,aura,aurai,auraient,aurais,aurait,auras,aurez,auriez,aurions,aurons,auront,aux,avaient,avais,avait,avec,avez,aviez,avions,avons,ayant,ayez,ayons,c,ce,ceci,cela,celà,ces,cet,cette,d,dans,de,des,du,elle,en,es,est,et,étaient,étais,était,étant,été,étée,étées,êtes,étés,étiez,étions,eu,eue,eues,eûmes,eurent,eus,eusse,eussent,eusses,eussiez,eussions,eut,eût,eûtes,eux,fûmes,furent,fus,fusse,fussent,fusses,fussiez,fussions,fut,fût,fûtes,ici,il,ils,j,je,l,la,le,les,leur,leurs,lui,m,ma,mais,me,même,mes,moi,mon,n,ne,nos,notre,nous,on,ont,ou,par,pas,pour,qu,que,quel,quelle,quelles,quels,qui,s,sa,sans,se,sera,serai,seraient,serais,serait,seras,serez,seriez,serions,serons,seront,ses,soi,soient,sois,soit,sommes,son,sont,soyez,soyons,suis,sur,t,ta,te,tes,toi,ton,tu,un,une,vos,votre,vous,y".split(',');

results = txt.split(',').filter(word => !to_remove.includes(word)).join();

console.log(results);
```

Here is the simple script that goes through all rows (starts from second row), takes the stop words from column B, text from column C, and puts result into column D:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet    = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
  var range    = sheet.getRange('B2:C' + last_row);
  var data     = range.getValues();
  var output   = [];

  for (row of data) {
    var stop_words = row[0].split(',');
    var txt        = row[1].split(',');
    var result     = txt.filter(word => !stop_words.includes(word)).join();
    output.push([result]);
  }

  sheet.getRange('D2:D'+last_row).setValues(output);
}
```

If the stop words are the same for every row the script can be even simpler shorter and faster:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row   = sheet.getLastRow();
  var stop_words = sheet.getRange('B2').getValue().split(','); // get stop words from B2
  var data       = sheet.getRange('C2:C' + last_row).getValues().flat();
  
  var output = data.map(row => 
    [row.split(',').filter(word => !stop_words.includes(word)).join()]
  );

  sheet.getRange('D2:D'+last_row).setValues(output);
}
```

**Update 2**

If you want a custom function it's here:

```
function NGRAMSFILTER(stop_words, ngrams) {
  var stop_words = stop_words.split(',');
  return ngrams.split(',').filter(word => !stop_words.includes(word)).join();
}
```

It takes a cell with stop words and cells with "ngrams" and returns the the "ngrams" that aren't among the stop words.

**Update 3**

Here is the custom function that collect all 'stop words' from column B:

```
function NGRAMSFILTER_ALL(ngrams) {
  var sheet      = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var last_row   = sheet.getLastRow();
  var stop_words = sheet.getRange('B2:B' + last_row).getValues().flat().join(',').split(',');
  return ngrams.split(',').filter(word => !stop_words.includes(word)).join();
}
```

Technically it works. But actually it could froze quite often if there are too much words and rows. And I see no way to speed it up. I'd advice to use a static script for such task.